# virtualenv and pip version inside

Tags: ubuntu, python, pip, virtualenv

I installed fresh Ubuntu 20.04 (which I believe comes with python3.8) and then additionally installed:

```
sudo apt install python3.9
sudo apt install python3.9-dev
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

I want to check what version of pip I’m running:

```
$ python3.8 -m pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

```
$ python3.9 -m pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Now, when I create a virtualenv (`virtualenv TestProject_XYZ -p 3.9`) and activate it I get the following:

```
$ python3.9 -m pip --version
pip 23.2.1 from ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/TestProject_XYZ/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

**Question**: I don't understand where virtualenv takes this version from (20.0.2 vs 23.2.1). I can't seem to find it anywhere in /usr/bin or /usr/lib

Comment: Try `python3.9 -c 'import pip; print(pip)'`